# Is there a convenient way to find $[G,G]$?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, normal-subgroups

I am concerned with finding the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ of a finite group $G$. Recall that the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ of a finite group $G$ is given by

> $[G,G] = \langle\{g^{-1}h^{-1}gh: g,h \in G\}\rangle$

I wondered if there are any propositions or theorems that make finding the commutator subgroup easier than merely just testing every pair $g,h$ of elements from $G$. Clearly, if we have a group such as $S_5$, this process could take a long time since $|S_5| = 120$. Is there a quicker way to find $[G,G]$ than just doing this process manually?

Comment: You gave a wrong definition of a commutator subgroup: You also need to take products of commutators.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Could you point out what's wrong with the definition? Maybe you could suggest an edit.

Comment: Your definition does not define a subgroup, just as I wrote.

Comment: $[G,G]$ is not the set of commutators, it is the subgroup generated by the commutators. So a general element is not a commutator, but a product of them.

Comment: To address the case of $S_5$, the commutator subgroup of any group is normal, and the only normal subgroups of $S_5$ are the trivial group and $A_5$. So you just need to find a single nontrivial commutator to conclude that the commutator subgroup is $A_5$.

Comment: @Mark Oh okay. I see what you're saying. How would we write that? Maybe seeing it written would help clarify my confusion.

Comment: I have edited, now it is written correctly.

Comment: @Mark Thank you

Comment: Actually you also need to rule out that the commutator subgroup of $S_5$ is itself! My bad. But it is easy to see that any commutator must be an even permutation...

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip alternatively, one can use the universal property of the abelianization $G/[G,G]$; in this case, since $S_{5}/A_{5} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $S_{5}/[S_{5},S_{5}]$ cannot be trivial.

Comment: The commutator subgroup is the smallest normal subgroup such that the quotient is abelian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Is there a convenient way to find find the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$?*

The answer depends on what we find convenient. We can use group theory
to determine the commutator subgroup for many well known groups. These results are already known.
That's very convenient. For example we know that
$$
[S_n,S_n]=A_n, \; n\ge 2.
$$
Similarly we know that
$$
[GL_n(K),GL_n(K)]=SL_n(K), \; n\ge 2.
$$
Of course one has to prove this using group theory. But certainly this will be more convenient than "doing it manually", where you were afraid that "this process could take a long time since $|S_n|=n!$ is large".